# What is the `file` Service Configuration in Symfony For?

Tags: php, symfony

Short Version: What does the Symfony `file: SomeFile.php` service configuration do?

Recently I entered an invalid service definition in a `service.yaml` file while working in a Symfony project.  I was greeted by this super useful error message

> The configuration key "foo" is unsupported for definition "App\Services\ServiceA" in "/Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/config/services.yaml". Allowed configuration keys are "alias", "parent", "class", "shared", "synthetic", "lazy", "public", "abstract", "deprecated", "factory", "file", "arguments", "properties", "configurator", "calls", "tags", "decorates", "decoration_inner_name", "decoration_priority", "autowire", "autoconfigure", "bind" in /Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/config/services.yaml").

I don't think I'd ever seen every valid configuration for a Symfony service listed somewhere before.  I'm trying to understand what the `file` configuration is for and how to use it.

I tried configuration a service using it

```
App\Services\ServiceA:
    file: SomeFile.php
```

and Symfony complained

> Warning: include_once(SomeFile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I tried placing a file named `SomeFile.php` at `src/SomeFile.php, and Symfony complained

> The autoloader expected class "App\SomeFile" to be defined in file "/Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/vendor/composer/../../src/SomeFile.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/config/services.yaml").

So I defined a class named `App\SomeFile` in `src/SomeFile.php`

```
#File: src/SomeFile.php
namespace App;
class SomeFile {
}
```

and Symfony loaded this file -- but when back to complaining

> Warning: include_once(SomeFile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in var/cache/dev/ContainerG6s3qUD/getServiceA2Service.php (line 11)

So finally, I checked out the `` file and saw it included this line

```
#File: var/cache/dev/ContainerG6s3qUD/getServiceA2Service.php
//...
include_once 'SomeFile.php';
//...
```

So, best I can tell is this `file` configuration is some sort of alternative to the composer autoloader -- but I can't find any docs on how to confirm thy suspicions or how to use it.

Can anyone help me understand that this configuration field is for?

Comment: Just recently the Symfony errors started to become more verbose.  Not sure how helpful this is since most people ignore them anyways.  That said, the file attribute is discussed here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/definitions.html#requiring-files Not something that get used much.

Comment: @Cerad FWIW I've found the new error messages to be helpful.  I bet a lot of people do read them -- you just only hear from the people that don't :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a [little help from some internet friends](https://twitter.com/__debo/status/1094421610390536193), who were able to [dig up some old documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#requiring-files), I now know that the `file` service configuration is for including a PHP immediately before the service gets loaded.

There's a few things that tripped me up.  First -- you need to use the `%kernel.root_dir%` parameter in order for this to work

```
App\Services\ServiceA:
    public: true
    file: "%kernel.root_dir%/foo.php"
```

The underlying container code expects this to be a full path.

Extra tricky was the following exception message

> The autoloader expected class "App\SomeFile" to be defined in file "/Users/alanstorm/Sites/symfony-4/my-project/vendor/composer/../../src/SomeFile.php".

It turns out this didn't have anything to do with my `file` configuration.  Instead, this error message was the result of the following default service.yaml configuration

```
_defaults:
    autowire: true
    public: true

App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Because my included `file`  was in `src`, Symfony's `resource` configuration seem to be trying to load it as a class file.  When it wasn't a class file, it complained.  Then, when the `file` loader tried to load a path without the `%kernel.root_dir%`, things were still sad.

If you're going to use these two configuration patterns together, you'll want to be sure to exclude your `file` file

```
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,foo.php}'
```